# how to to make sinon return non promise I do mock expect

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sinon

I am using sinon to mock a return for a function and here is my code:

```
  sandbox.mock(monitoring).expects('getHttpRequestDuration').resolves({
    startTimer: () => {}
  });
```

The problem here is the return is wrapped in a promise and the actual function is not using any await

```
 const end = httpRequestTimer.startTimer();
```

is there a way I can return only

```
     {
        startTimer: () => {}
      }
```

not wrapped in a promise?

Comment: Does it work if you change resolves to returns?

Comment: Good point but unfortunately no TypeError: sandbox.mock(...).expects(...).return is not a function :(

Comment: You're missing an `s` there :)?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum ooops very nice yeah worked can you post it as an answer and I will approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resolves` returns a promise. The equivalent method in sinon to return a value is `.returns`:

```js
  sandbox.mock(monitoring).expects('getHttpRequestDuration').returns({
    startTimer: () => {}
  });
```

See [`stub.returns`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/) in our docs.